# Can't get fcm token in flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get the FCM token in the `main` function, but it doesn't work and it gets stuck at the splash screen. Even the `try/catch` bloc doesn't show the error. May I get help, please?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
  }
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FirebaseMessagingConfiguration().initializeNotifications();
  setupDioLocator();
  await setupLocalLocator();
  await getIt<LocalRepository>().getPreferredLanguage();
  try{
    final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken(vapidKey: Keys.FCM_WEB_PUBLIC_KEY);
    print("FCM TOKEN: $fcmToken");
  }catch(error){
    print('Token error: $error');
  }
  runApp(Stop(key: stopKey));
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. However, I don't develop on the web, so I don't use the `vapidKey`, so maybe your problem is related to that key?

Answer (score 1):

You might be experiencing issues because you copied the VapidKey incorrectly. You should make sure that the VapidKey is correct. Because I had a problem due to this the other day. In the Firebase Console where the VapidKey is displayed, you can select the entire VapidKey by double-clicking on it and then copy it.

Comment: This problem is solved a long ago, but flutter web doesn't receive notifications